# Splitting python code into different files (added picture of directory)

Tags: python, pandas

As my python code is getting longer, I would like to split it into a different files for better organization. In the same folder I created 2 files 'firstfile.py' and '2ndfile.py'

Below is the code of 'firstfile'

```
import pandas as pd    
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,4],'b':[2,1]})
```

Below is the code of '2ndfile'

```
import firstfile    
print(firstfile.df)
```

Can I know why does the below error appear when i run '2ndfile'?

> ImportError: No module named 'firstfile'

Hi, I tried the suggestions below including using dot something but it still does not work. Below is a screen shot of my directory. Is it related to some sys.path problem? I am currently using Spyder 2, python 3.5.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that both files are in the same directory? And the naming is correct?

Comment: I tried this quickly and it worked. Make sure you have no typos and show the content of the folder containing the files.

Comment: Precisely how are you running `2ndfile`? Do you type a command? If so, what? Do you click a button in an IDE? Something else?

Comment: Try `import .firstfile` (note the dot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from using Spyder2 python 3.5 to pyCharm solved the issue.

Comment: It may have solved the issue itself since PyCharm does a lot of environment and scope settings for  (=instead of) you, but that way you are missing a very important lecture on whole python import system. You might run into troubles when trying to run your code as a standalone script (e.g. via terminal or cron). Just sayin...

Answer (score 1):

Try importing it with the `from . import firstfile`. Maybe you have Python3 which doesn't allow for implicit imports.